# Timed message sent to specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm looking to use my below code in discord.js for my bot to send a specific message to a specific channel set at a certain amount of time intervals. How can I please make this happen?

```
client.channels.get("550449channelidhere40447774").send(`<@&566483roleidhere34268683> i don't forget! somethingh somewthing`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a setInterval. This would look like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
client.channels.get("550449channelidhere40447774").send(`<@&566483roleidhere34268683> i don't forget! somethingh somewthing`);
}, 10000);
```

The 10000 is the time interval. In this case I set it to 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds)

Comment: TypeError: client.channels.get is not a function